# In the C program why am I getting an error of sample.c:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `pow

Tags: c, math, flow-control

I am making a program C program that finds out whether a number is an Armstrong number or not.
Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(){
    int inp,count,d1,d2,rem;
    float arm;
    printf("the number: ");
    scanf("%d",&inp);

    d1 = inp;
    d2 = inp;
    // for counting the number of digits
    while(d1 != 0){
        d1 /= 10; 
        ++count;
    }
    //for checking whether the number is anarmstrong number or not
    while(d2 != 0){
        rem = (d2 % 10);
        arm += pow(rem,count);
        d2 /= 10;
    }
    printf("%f",arm);
    return 0;

}
```

*(file name: sample.c)*

I expect the program to show the output as:

```
the number:
```

but it shows the following error:

```
usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccleyeW0.o: in function `main':
sample.c:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have even used the command GCC `-o sample sample.c -lm` but still getting an error.
So I would like to know what is causing this error and how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: The `-lm` should have solved it. Please remove all the `.o` files and try again.

Comment: Double-check you're using `-lm`.  Lack of `-lm` is virtually always what causes this problem.

Comment: `float arm;` -> `float arm = 0;`

Comment: You should also initialise `count` to `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments above, you should compile your program using `gcc -o sample sample.c -lm`. The `-lm` argument ensures that your program is linked against the math library.

Besides that, it is not only good style, but *necessary* to initialise variables in C before you use them. In this case, the variables `arm` and `count` are not initialised. Especially the value of `arm` will certainly cause trouble, because it will have the value of whatever is at its assigned memory location (garbage value), when you run your program, which leads to non-deterministic behaviour. Initialising both variables to 0 should fix your code.